# How to sort the columns horizontally largest-to-smallest by second row in list of data frames in R?

Tags: r, sorting, row

There is a list of data frames that the second row of each data frame is the total row. I want to sort the columns horizontally largest-to-smallest by total? Here is a sample of a data frame.

```
structure(list(PROVINCE = c("Percentage", "Total", "11", "11", 
"11", "11"), DISTRICT = c("Percentage", "Total", "1", "2", "4", 
"4"), SUB_DISTRI = c("Percentage", "Total", "21", "21", "10", 
"10"), VILLAGE = c("Percentage", "Total", "14", "5", "22", "24"
), `0` = c("0.111897382265155", "59.930000305176", "0", "9.1700000762939", 
"0", "0"), `9` = c("0.545072631055998", "291.930001258852", "0", 
"0", "9.6999998092651", "10"), `11` = c("0.0171216252074662", 
"9.1700000762939", "9.1700000762939", "0", "0", "0"), `1167` = c("0.325908361471381", 
"174.550001144409", "0", "36.6800003051756", "0", "0")), row.names = c(34L, 
33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use `order`. Since you have four columns of non-numeric data, and your numeric data (for some reason) is formatted as character, you'll need to do something like:

```
df[, c(1:4, order(as.numeric(unlist(
  df[2, 5:ncol(df)], use.names=FALSE)), decreasing = TRUE) + 4)]
```

Breaking it down:

- `df2[2, 5:ncol(df)]` selects second row and all the numeric columns
- `as.numeric(unlist(., use.names = FALSE))` converts that to numeric values so you can sort them
- `order` returns the sorted positions. `decreasing = TRUE` says to `order` them from largest to smallest
- `c(1:4, ... + 4)` is required to keep the original four columns (in their place) and adjust the output of `order` accordingly